# Linux file system events and python's shutil

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, shutil

In Java 7 I can use to file system events like file creation, modification, etc. However, when I move a file using Python's `shutil` module, my program doesn't receive the event.
Does anyone knows why this happens, and how can I counter it?

Comment: Could you show the code you are using?

Comment: Unfortunately it is on a different network, however it is a very basic java code...

Comment: @AviadNissel I think he means the Python code. I'm not sure what you mean by "my program doesn't receive the event." `shutil` works fine for me, on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 (I dual-boot). You probably aren't using the functions correctly, hence we want to see the code to correct any mistakes.